# how do you merge 2 different databases?

Tags: sql

Id like to know what can i do to keep 2 databases in 2 different locations, with the same structures except different, data sinchronized.

If i have to be more detailed the problem is that i have 2 stores in which i have a server each. The reason is that there are network issues (can't be helped) so sometimes one of the stores has no internet for over 2 days, still we want to be able to enter information in the system (let say a billing system). So in order to solve this i will be making one store to enter invoices with odd numbers and the other store with even numbers so that when a store has  no internet they can still work. Now here is what i don't know how to do: when internet is back again i want the 2 databases to sinchronize their data. How do i do that?

I'll be using MySQL

Thanks!

Comment: Which Database technology you are using is it SQL Server, Oracle, MySql etc?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151257.aspx

Comment: Even/odd is a bad idea.  What happens when you get a third store?  Probably, each store needs its own set of invoices.  If they must share the same "source", then you need a central server for them; if you're not allowed any gaps you're screwed, because they'll get out of sync pretty fast (different numbers of invoices).

Comment: Anuraj i'll be using MySQL.

@Clockwork-Muse then what would be a better approach? to solve that i ssue, so that both stores can work without internet and when there is internet again the databases sinchronize without risking data overwriting.

Comment: Note that in either case you need to be storing the "originating" store (to protect against generating scheme changes).  After that it depends on accounting laws; some _require_ there be no gaps in sequence (which makes things difficult in other ways, too), and whether you're allowed to use separate generators will depend on laws too.  From one standpoint, each store would be its own entity, meaning separate sets of numbers.  Otherwise you need out-of-band communication (like a telephone call) and the ability to manually enter an invoice number (has other problems, though).

Comment: i'm kind of in a dead end here then :c What is advisable to do in this situation? i can't close one store just because there is no internet ;~;